# CloudKit - How to modify the record in the background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background, cloudkit

My App can use location updates in the background now.
Then, can we modify the record in the background when a user is moving?

Code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
var locationManager: CLLocationManager!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapView.delegate = self

    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    locationManager.delegate = self

    locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true

}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]) {
    recordLocation()   
}


func recordLocation() {

    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "accountID == %@", argumentArray: [myID!])
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Accounts", predicate: predicate)

    publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: {(records, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("error1: \(error)")
            return
        }

        for record in records! {

            record["currentLocation"] = self.mapView.userLocation.location

            publicDatabase.save(record, completionHandler: {(record, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print("error2: \(error)")
                    return
                }
                print("success!")
            })
        }
    })
}
```

[image - Capability of Background Modes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdSSz.png)

By the way, everything is fine as long as my app runs in the foreground.

### Versions

Xcode 12.2 / Swift 4.2

### Summary

Could you please tell me how to modify the record in the background? In the first place, can we do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't have Background fetch on.  それをオンにしてね。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。 I did that, but can’t record my location updates.

Comment: You also need the Required background modes key in the Info.plist, I think.  info.plistにそのキーを追加してみてね。

Comment: When I put a check mark, background modes key seems to be added automatically in the Info.plist. So I still haven’t been able to perform. I will try to read Developer Documentation, for example [Preparing Your UI to Run in the Background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background). すでにキーは自動で追加されていたようで、効果はありませんでした(´･_･`)

Comment: I misunderstood. I have already recorded my location, but had failed to get  the latest one. In other words, this problem have been solved from the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I misunderstood. I had already recorded my location in the background, but had failed to get the latest one.

```
record["currentLocation"] = self.mapView.userLocation.location
```

By using  this code, I had recorded the location **the last moment that I were viewing MKMapView.**

In other words, the problem, recording in the background, have been solved from the beginning.

I rewrote as the following code:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[CLLocation]) {

    if let location = locations.first {
        recordLocation(currentLocation: location)
    }

}


func recordLocation(currentLocation: CLLocation) {

    let publicDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase

    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "accountID == %@", argumentArray: [myID!])
    let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Accounts", predicate: predicate)

    publicDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil, completionHandler: {(records, error) in

        if let error = error {
            print("error1: \(error)")
            return
        }

        for record in records! {

            record["currentLocation"] = currentLocation as CLLocation

            publicDatabase.save(record, completionHandler: {(record, error) in

                if let error = error {
                    print("error2: \(error)")
                    return
                }
                print("success!: \(String(describing: currentLocation))")
            })
        }
    })

}
```